# Receive error from Unexpected token Doctype Html

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm using [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [react-router-dom](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) and [express](https://expressjs.com/) in my project. When I send a request by clicking on a link everything works well but if I send a request via browser it doesn't work. However, for some requests in a browser like `http://localhost:8000/` or `http://localhost:8000/admin` works well but for some requests like `http://localhost:8000/admin/users` or `http://localhost:8000/admin/account` doesn't work well.

> Error in browser says : `bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and it points on 
>   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I just needed to edit `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>`.I've edited `bundle.js` to `/bundle.js`.